# PropagationFlags enumeration [Access Control Entries (ACEs)] in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

what is the sense of having a flags enum like PropagationFlags if the content of the enum is:

1. **None**:   Specifies that no inheritance flags are set.
2. **NoPropagateInherit**: Specifies that the ACE is not propagated to child objects.
3. **InheritOnly**:    Specifies that the ACE is propagated only to child objects. This includes both container and leaf child objects.

What will be the meaning of a variable with **None** | **InheritOnly** or **NoPropagateInherit** | **InheritOnly**?

I'm missing something or is this a .Net framework bad design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `None` in that enum just means that you're not setting any flags, essentially that you want the default behavior. The [framework guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx) state that the zero (and therefor non-set or essentially null) should be called None. In this case the name might be confusing because you may think it means 'No propagation' but it doesn't. The other two values are intended to be `OR`'d together potentially. `OR`'ing with zero always returns the original value.

Comment: Well, I get what you mean with None but if you read teh explanation of NoPropagateInherit and InheritOnly, how can I OR [Specifies that the ACE is not propagated to child objects] | [Specifies that the ACE is propagated only to child objects]

Comment: This is one of those "yes you can but why would you" things. I'll point you to the comment here by Jerry Issa where he says OR'ing them togehter "means that the ACE would apply to children of the current object but not to the object itself or to grandchildren or other descendants of the object": http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/4072.aspx#255136

Comment: I made a chart of the mapping between the file permissions dialogs and resulting permissions: http://bit.ly/inheritMatrix

Answer (score 3):

I have drawn this small diagram which helps to quickly understand the effect of both PropagationFlags and InheritanceFlags.

[image: PropagationFlags and InheritanceFlags]

Here is also a good MSDN link which explains some combination use cases:
[ACL Propagation Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229747(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)